# Recreating colored glass shader from VRay/Max to Blender/Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, shaders, glass

**Edit: Blend file:**

[image]

---

I am converting a somewhat simple scene from 3DSMax/VRay to Blender/Cycles. I'm almost done with the conversion, but I am having trouble with matching the glass shader used in the original. Since a picture is worth a thousand words, here's where I am at for reference:

**Original scene rendered in 3DS Max and VRay:**

[image: Original Scene]

**The same render, highlighting the glass that I can't seem to match:**

[image: Original Scene Arrows]

**Here is my progress, rendered in Blender/Cycles:**

[image: My Scene]

**Here are the glass material settings in Max:**

[image: 3DS Max Glass Material Slate]

**Here's the glass shader I'm currently working with:**

[image: Cycles Glass Nodegroup]

Finally, here's a side by side comparison:

[image: Side by Side]

As you can see, the glass from 3dsmax looks a lot more translucent in the middle. It just looks better. I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong, but I think the falloff map used in max is part of the solution.

Here is a stripped version of the scene for anyone here who wants to help:

[image]

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit1:**

---

So I arrived a material that comes a lot closer. I am updating this post so others may learn from it.

Here is the final render with the glass shader:

[image: Final]

Here is the shader itself:

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried to give it a bit more transparency or brighten a bit the color?

Comment: @moonboots I tried both. Changing the color didn't really help much, but I think lowering the alpha/transparency might be something worth trying. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: maybe share this object only (or a part of it), with the same background and lights so that we can give a try? It really looks like your object is not transparent enough...

Comment: @moonboots no problem. I'll delete everything but the object in question and upload in about 2-3 min.

Comment: @moonboots Scene has been added to the post.

Comment: I've tried but your version is pretty close to the original version, I hope someone will help

Comment: Thanks for trying at least! Holding out hope that someone can figure it out.